# Getting retry backoff error and not restarting kafka-streams on marathon

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have kafka with high availability. We run multiple kafka streams and spark jobs on multiple topics.

But, we found a strange issue of sending record. The error that we received goes like that

> task [0_4] Error sending record (key 27314 value example.jar.class timestamp 1535741326818) to topic TOPIC_NAME due to {}; No more records will be sent and no more offsets will be recorded for this task.
>   You can increase producer parameter `retries` and `retry.backoff.ms` to avoid this error.
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [0_4] Abort sending since an error caught with a previous record (key 27314 value example.jar.class@6f7cb16c timestamp 1535741326818) to topic TOPIC_NAME due to Expiring 1 record(s) for TOPIC_NAME-4: 42708 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
>   You can increase producer parameter `retries` and `retry.backoff.ms` to avoid this error.

We also tried with keeping linger time 0 so that it will process immediately as it received. but no luck.

Our configuration is as below

```
retries: 3
retry-backoff-ms: 20000
replication-factor: 1
reconnect-backoff-ms: 60000
max-poll-records: 1000
session-timeout-ms: 300000
```

Also, we have marathon to manage kafka-streams but it's not detecting it as failure and not restarting automatically.

So, I want to either run kafka streams properly or restart marathon automatically on these kind of errors (last option).

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. I have 5 brokers in the cluster and 32 partitions of the topic with replication factor of 2.

I forgot that kafka streams create internal topics. And by default they have replication factor of 1. And the reason was that when we try to kill one broker the internal topic is not reachable any more since it doesn't have replicas. So try to set replication factor of internal topics the same as of source topics. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

If an error occurs in Kafka Stream, only the internal `StreamThread` dies, but there is no exception thrown in the "main" thread. I guess, that is why the error is not detected. It's recommended to register an uncaught exception handle on the `KafkaStreams` client to get informed about dying threads and to react accordingly.

About the error itself. It might be a known issue (compare [KIP-91](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-91+Provide+Intuitive+User+Timeouts+in+The+Producer) for details). You can try to increase parameter `request.timeout.ms` as a workaround.

Comment: About "react accordingly". I have registered an `uncaughtExceptionHandler` that closes the Streams application resources gently and ends the task. Is there a way to recover from the thread dying, without having to tear down the whole application? Is it safe? Is another `StreamThread` spawn to keep up with number of threads expected?

Comment: To recover threads, you need to `KafkaStreams#close()` the existing client, create a new one, and restart it.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Is this case even now? With version 2.3.0? We use Kafka with Kerberos. Producers and Consumers always recover after a cluster bounce, but the streams app does not. After the Stream Threads die, we have to manually restart out app. Was hoping there'd be an easy way to recover.

Comment: The behavior is still the same and there is no other way to recover threads automatically atm. We actually hope to address this issue in Kafka 2.7 -- stay tuned.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax we have the same error in the log and we have uncaughtExceptionHandler handler attached to the KafkaStreams object. The handler is supposed to print some details about the exception, however this handler is never called in the case of the above error. Should this error trigger call to the handler?

Comment: If a thread dies, the handler should be called.